# Pandas dataframe lineplot and stacked bar plot

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, plot

**The situation:**
I have a very small dataset with a year column and an event success or fail indicating binary column.

[image]

I created two series from the binary column which counts the successful and the failed events.

Successful events:

```
success_count = hungary_data[hungary_data['success']==1]["iyear"].value_counts().sort_index()
success_count
```

Output:
[image]

Failed events:

```
fail_count = hungary_data[hungary_data['success']==0]["iyear"].value_counts().sort_index()
fail_count
```

Output:
[image]

**The problem:**
My problem is that I just can't display these two series on a linegraph, nor stacked bar graph.

Here is my code and output for the linechart:

```
plt.plot(success_count, label = "Sikeres támadások")
plt.plot(fail_count, label = "Sikertelen támadások")
plt.ylim(ymin=0)
plt.legend(loc=2)
plt.show()
```

Output:
[image]

As you can see the failed counts are not displayed at all (however there is a legend for them), the years are displayed by half increment (which is also wrong).

My stacked bar attempt is also a failure:

```
plt.bar([1989,1990,1991], success_count, label = "Sikeres támadások")
plt.bar([1989,1990,1991], fail_count, label = "Sikertelen támadások")
plt.legend(loc=2)
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

**Questions:**

1. How should my code look like in order to display both linecharts for successful and failed events (when there is no failed attempt for a year, it should be zero)?
2. Why are years displayed by half increment (there should be no decimal for years) and what is the solution to avoid it?
3. How should my code look like in case of stacked bar?

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: In your first plot, you just have a single data point for `fail_count` which is (1991, 1). Hence it isn't visible on the plot unless you use a visible marker. I the first plot, you can try using both markers and lines to highlight the datapoints. To avoid the half integers, one way is to manually set the `xticks` as something like `plt.xticks(range(1989,1993))`

Comment: Please know how to create a [`Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Sandeep Kadapa, I am trying my best to stick to the example you mention. Please, please so much pinpoint me what is wrong with my post. The problem is reproducable, I sticked to the minimal code and also it is complete. What on earth is wrong with this post? Please let me know. I read that link like 50 times. Could you also stick to your comment to be minimal, complete and verifiable also? Like letting me know which part does not comply with the rules... Thank you so..... so..much!

Comment: Pictures are always a bad idea. You have code. Why don't you copy your code? Posting pictures of code is like trying to drink a picture of a glass of milk.

Comment: Ok. Will avoid that in the future.

Comment: Why only in the future? Why not now? Why don't you exchange the pictures for code in this question?

Comment: Here you go! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following.

First of all, rename your `success_count` and `fail_count` Serieses:

```
success_count.rename('Sikeres támadások', inplace=True)
fail_count.rename('Sikertelen támadások', inplace=True)
```

Then you can just plot the `concat` of the two.

```
pd.concat([success_count, fail_count],axis=1).plot(kind='bar', stacked='True')
```